# Como criar uma ArrayList de arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, array, winforms

Estou com alguns problemas em criar uma List de arrays, estou usando Visual C#, .NET 3.5.

Código:

```
using Database;
//...
namespace Sample {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        //...
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if ((TextBox1.Text).Equals("") || (TextBox2.Text).Equals("")) {
                MessageBox.Show(null, "Preencha todos os campos!", "Erro");
            } else {
                ClassDatabase Call = new ClassDatabase();
                Call.RegDatabase(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
                //...
            }
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

```
namespace Database {
    class ClassDatabase {
        List<string[]> InfoList = new List<string[]>();
        public void RegDatabase(String A, String B) {
            string[] DataSet = new string[2];
            DataSet[0] = A;
            DataSet[1] = B;
            this.InfoList.AddRange(DataSet);
        } public bool InDatabase (String A, String B) {
            int j = InfoList.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i ++) {
                string[] DataGet = new string[2];
                DataGet = this.InfoList[i];
                if (DataGet[0].Equals(A) && DataGet[1].Equals(B)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Database;
//...
namespace Sample {
    public partial class Form2 : Form {
        //...
        ClassDatabase Call = new ClassDatabase();
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (Call.InDatabase(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)) {
                //...
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show(null, "Falha ao entrar.", "Erro");
            }
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

O que era para acontecer aí é um registro, depois uma validação.

O usuário se registra e aperta o botão para confirmar, as informações são enviadas para o método `RegDatabase` da classe `ClassDatabase`, que adiciona essas informações à lista do tipo *string[]*, `InfoList`. Quando o usuário tenta entrar, ele coloca as informações nas *TextBox* e clica no botão, isso envia as informações para o outro método da classe `ClassDatabase`, o `InDatabase`, este método pega a lista `InfoList` e abre cada array, comparando os dados de cada array dentro da lista `InfoList` com os dados inseridos pelo usuário; se satisfazer a condição do *if*, o método retorna **true** e entra no sistema, se não, retorna **false** e isso gera uma mensagem de erro.

Bom, isso é o que eu tentei fazer com que ocorresse, porém não é o que acontece, o problema, talvez, seja minha falta de experiência, mas de qualquer forma, como poderia fazer o descrito acima?

Há alguma maneira mais prática de fazer esse registro/validação (DLL, por exemplo)? Se sim, qual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu percebi que sua classe apresentou alguns erros de codificação, fiz as alterações sobre o seu código e ficou assim:

***1) Opção***

**Código**

```
    public class ClassDatabase
    {
        protected List<string[]> InfoList = new List<string[]>();
        public void RegDatabase(String A, String B)
        {
            InfoList.Add(new String[2] { A, B });
        }
        public bool InDatabase(String A, String B)
        {
            bool ret = false;            
            int i = 0;
            while (ret == false && i < InfoList.Count)
            {
                if (InfoList[i] != null)
                {
                    if (A.Equals(InfoList[i][0]) && 
                        B.Equals(InfoList[i][1]))
                    {
                        ret = true;
                    }                    
                }
                i++;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

**Como utilizar**

```
ClassDatabase db = new ClassDatabase();
//ADICIONANDO VALORES
db.RegDatabase("Valor1", "Valor2");
db.RegDatabase("Valor3", "Valor4");

//VERIFICANDO SE O VALOR EXISTE
bool ret = db.InDatabase("Valor3", "Valor4");
```

**Debugando Código**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Obs: Perceba que ta funcionando e ele encontrou o valor dentro do `List<String[]>` !!!*

---

***2) Opção***

**Outra maneira com persistência dos dados até o fechamento do programa**

**Código**

```
public static class ClassDatabase
{
    static ClassDatabase()
    {
        ClassDatabase.InfoList = new List<string[]>();
    }
    public static List<string[]> InfoList { get; private set; }
    public static void RegDatabase(String A, String B)
    {
        InfoList.Add(new String[2] { A, B });
    }
    public static bool InDatabase(String A, String B)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (ret == false && i < InfoList.Count)
        {
            if (InfoList[i] != null)
            {
                if (A.Equals(InfoList[i][0]) &&
                    B.Equals(InfoList[i][3]))
                {
                    ret = true;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**Como utilizar**

*O Form1 será responsável por preecher ele a primeira vez.*

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
       //ADICIONANDO VALORES
       ClassDatabase.RegDatabase("Valor1", "Valor2");
       ClassDatabase.RegDatabase("Valor3", "Valor4");
       ClassDatabase.RegDatabase("Valor5", "Valor6");
       ClassDatabase.RegDatabase("Valor7", "Valor8");
}
```

*O Form2 (ou qualquer form) poderá enxergar os valores adicionados até que o programa feche.*

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //ClassDatabase.InDatabase
   //ClassDatabase.RegDatabase
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Referência:**

- [static (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/98f28cdx.aspx)
- [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: É isso sim, mas tem um problema... Suponhamos que haja um Form3 que surge após a validação dos dados. Ok, faço que devo fazer nesse Form3, quando eu saio desse Form3 de volta para o Form2, os dados "somem", insiro os dados que cadastrei anteriormente e tento validar, porém nada acontece, como se estivesse sendo iniciado pela primeira vez. O que pode ser?

Comment: Setar esse Array como Static acredito que resolva

Comment: Na própria classe `ClassDatabase`?

Comment: Vou colocar um adendo nesse exemplo, wait ...

Comment: Pronto, é só utilizar a segunda opção

Comment: Poderia me explicar o motivo de poder apenas chamar os métodos da classe `ClassDatabase` usando o próprio nome da classe ao invés de uma instância?

Comment: Quando utilize o modificador static a ClassDatabase não precisa ser mais instâncias, e você pode acessar seus metodos, propriedades diretamente pelo nome da classe como está no exemplo, coloquei outra referencia que isso bem mais claro para o seu entendimento. No seu caso como queria acessar ela de qualquer form é a maneira de não perder os dados que eram carregados no inicio do seu programa